# Representing by $m$ every $n\in\mathbb N$ such that the last $m$ digits of $n^2$ is equal to those of $n$

Tags: number-theory

I found the following sentences in a book without any additional information.

"There are four numbers $n\in\mathbb N$ which satisfy the following condition for each $m\in\mathbb N$.

**Condition** : The last $m$ digits of $n^2$ is equal to those of $n$.

Here, suppose that $n=1$ satisfies the condition for any $m$. It is known that these numbers can be represented by $m$."

It's easy to prove that $10^m$ satisfies the condition. Also, you can easily get the followings:

For the $m=1$ case, we have $1,5,6,10$.

For the $m=2$ case, we have $1,25,76,100$.

For the $m=3$ case, we have $1,376,625,1000$.

I've tried to represent such $n$ by $m$, but I'm facing difficulty. Then, here is my question.

**Question** : Could you show me how to represent such $n$ by $m$?

Comment: Can you figure out, when $n^2-n=n(n-1)$ is divisible by $10^m$? Notice that $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$ and that $10^m=2^m\cdot 5^m.$ Chinese remainder theorem is your friend.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yes. I got four types. Two types remains unsolved. One is the '$n\equiv0$ (mod $2^m$) and $n\equiv1$ (mod $5^m$)' case. The other is the '$n\equiv1$ (mod $2^m$) and $n\equiv0$ (mod $5^m$)' case.

Comment: But you know that by the Chinese Remainder theorem each has a unique solution modulo $10^m$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:Yes, but I would like to know how to represent them by $m$.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem gives an explicit if somewhat messy recipe. If you want ugly, you can use Euler's Theorem to produce the multipliers asked for by CRT.

Comment: You do know that $5$ has order $2^{m-2}$ modulo $2^m$, don't ya? The other multiplier is trickier: $2$ is of order $4$ modulo $5$, of order a factor of $20=4\cdot5$ modulo $5^2$, of order a facotr of $100=4\cdot5^2$ modulo $5^3$ et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got the followings:

$$1, 10^m, 5^{2^{m-1}}-\lfloor{\frac{5^{2^{m-1}}}{10^m}}\rfloor10^{m},\left(1+\lfloor\frac{5^{2^{m-1}}}{10^m}\rfloor\right)10^m-5^{2^{m-1}}+1$$

**Proof** : Let $N=5^{2^{m-1}}$.
We know that $N\equiv0$ (mod $5^m$) and that $N\equiv1$ (mod $2^{m+1}$). Hence, $N\equiv1$ (mod $2^m$). Here let's take a natural number $\bar N$ such that $\bar N\equiv N$ (mod $10^m$) and $1\le \bar N\le 10^m$. Then, we can say that $\bar N=N-\lfloor\frac{N}{10^m}\rfloor10^m$ satisfies the condition.

Next, let $N^{\prime}=10^m+1-\bar N$. Then, we know that $1\le N^{\prime}\le 10^m$. Hence, we know that $N^{\prime}$ satisfies the condition.

Now the proof is completed.